# Terry/Gina "testes" double entendree

Tags: puns

On  a series (Brooklyn 99 S2E2 beginning), one character announces their decision to get a vasectomy, and lets the others have fun at him. One such response is "No need to be so testes". I understand the connection to the issue at hand (testicles), but I don't understand the other part of the double entendree, can you explain it for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like a pun on the word "testy", meaning grumpy or bad tempered. If someone was behaving in such a way, another person might tell them "no need to be so testy".

For example, from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/testy#examples

> that coworker would be easier to get along with if she weren't so testy all the time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nice answer.  Don't you want to change the gender in your example, though?  So the pun will work?